# How add tap function to listview.builder item?

Tags: flutter, dart

Could you tell me how to add tap `function` to listview builder item?

I want to go on a new screen when tapped on item.

I create 2 screens, standart and vip and added them to `main.dart` for routes.

Thanks for helping

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 350,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 6),
        itemCount: ultraComputers().length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            width: 350,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(ultraComputers()[index].image),
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: 300,
                  left: 16,
                  child: Text(
                    ultraComputers()[index].description,
                    style: GoogleFonts.jura(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 15,
                  left: 20,
                  child: Text(
                    ultraComputers()[index].city,
                    style: GoogleFonts.jura(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                  ),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a "tap function" to items within a ListView, I'd suggest wrapping the item Widget with a `GestureDetector` Widget, allowing you to add a "onTap" property:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
      ...function here...
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
        width: 350,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(ultraComputers()[index].image),
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 300,
              left: 16,
              child: Text(
                ultraComputers()[index].description,
                style: GoogleFonts.jura(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 40),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 15,
              left: 20,
              child: Text(
                ultraComputers()[index].city,
                style: GoogleFonts.jura(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks! And how to choose which item you clicked on?

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly, choosing a specific item is done via the index.
You can pass said item as a parameter into the new Page and then use it to access the same info as you would on the first page, within the List.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the widget you're returning in your listview.builder with a GestureDetector widget and implement the onTap property

Comment: Thanks! And how to choose which item you clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

there is another way that it can help .
you can use List View separated and this list cat return List Tile .
and List Tile have on Tap Function .

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html